# Can't correct a spelling error

Tags: discussion, bug, edits

I was looking at the post [Pros and Cons of Different macro function / inline methods in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571392/pros-and-cons-of-different-macro-function-inline-methods-in-c) regarding macros as I was considering my response to a c code review.

I then noticed a simple one letter typo/spelling error in the first answer and wanted to correct it (the anal engineer in me).  I thought it would also be helpful as it would remove the distraction to others like me.

I was frustrated that I could not fix it because I had to change at least 6 characters.  I considered doing that; but the rest of the answer seemed fine except for the typo and doing bogus edits to meet the 6 character limit that seemed inappropriate.

What is the best way to handle this?

I could not find a stack overflow rule that says you shouldn't fix typos; so, is this a bug?

[What is the etiquette for modifying posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11474/what-is-the-etiquette-for-modifying-posts) seems to indicate that fixing a spelling/grammar error is an appropriate edit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not a bug.  It's due to the amount of reputation you have; since you don't have 2K or more rep, your edits are peer-reviewed.

The idea with the limit is to prevent very new users from making one or two character changes, thus slowing down the peer review process.  Users with more than 2K rep don't have this limitation, and so they can make the edit without it needing to go through peer review.

In your scenario, something *that* minor shouldn't be handled by yourself without the "Edit Anywhere" privilege.  Considering that the OP is still active on the site, you could have pinged them to let them know of the typo.  Outside of that, your options are limited; I can't speak to any chatrooms here that would be able to take something like that on.  Making a post for every minor thing that needs to be edited on Meta isn't a habit I want you to get into, but considering this case concerned general confusion, it's fine.

I've since made the edit.

Comment: abut should be about

Comment: @markshancock:  "Straightforward' was also misspelled, so I took care of that, too.

Comment: would it have been appropriate the do to innocuous edits to get it above the 6 character limit

Comment: @markshancock: Innocuous, no.  Make every edit substantial.  There were probably more things to improve than just that one typo (like the two I found), but try your best to do comprehensive edits. Innocuous edits aren't the best approach in this scenario.